# Android Duktape NullPointerException while Internet is not there

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, duktape

I am getting a null Exception when there is no internet on my mobile.

it is showing error here:

val results: String? = jsBinder.androidWrapper(functionName, gson.toJson(input))

- input is Any type
- functionName is a string type
- gson is a GSON type

  ```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Null Duktape context - did you close your Duktape?
        at com.squareup.duktape.Duktape.call(Native Method)
        at com.squareup.duktape.Duktape.access$100(Duktape.java:26)
        at com.squareup.duktape.Duktape$1.invoke(Duktape.java:132)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy19.androidWrapper(Unknown Source)
        at com.repository.network.js.JsEngineProvider.get(JsEngineProvider.kt:60)
        at com.repository.network.js.JsEngineProvider.access$get(JsEngineProvider.kt:12)
        at com.repository.network.js.JsEngineProvider$getImplementation$1.invoke(JsEngineProvider.kt:54)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy20.getGuidesSnapshot(Unknown Source)
  ```

Comment: This is not a duktape problem. The software which uses duktape here is the culprit.

Comment: i am using version = "com.squareup.duktape:duktape-android:1.3.0" so is this correct one ?@MikeLischke